# Como alterar a ordem da data de um implode vindo de um datepicker jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, get, datepicker

Tenho o seguinte $_get :

```
if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    $v_ocorrencia = $_GET['ocorrencia'];
    $datainicio = $_GET['datainicio'];
    $datafinal  = $_GET['datafinal'];

echo 'valor recebido: '. $v_ocorrencia;
    echo 'valor recebido: '. $v_datainicio." 00:00:00.000";
        echo 'valor recebido: '. $v_datafinal." 00:00:00.000";
```

Com o implode ele me retorna a data:

```
valor recebido: 1
valor recebido: 2016-17-11 00:00:00.000
valor recebido: 2016-26-11 00:00:00.000
```

Até ai tudo bem, mais não to conseguindo alterar a ordem da data,ela ta saindo:
`Y-dd-mm` e preciso que seja `Y-mm-dd`

Observação: a data esta vindo de um  [Datepicker do jquery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **Datepicker** tem formatação de entrada:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

[**Olha na documentação**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Mas se deseja inverter somente no php, basta formatar o valor:

```
$valor = '2016-17-11 00:00:00.000';

formatDateEng($valor);

function formatDateEng($valor)
{
    list($dateStr, $timeStr) = explode(' ', $valor);
    list($y, $d, $m) = explode('-', $dateStr);
    return "{$y}-{$m}-{$d} {$timeStr}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente o seguinte:

```
$v_datainicio=date_create($v_datainicio." 00:00:00.000");
$v_datafinal=date_create($v_datafinal." 00:00:00.000");
echo 'valor recebido: '. date_format($v_datafinal,"Y-d-m H:i:s");
echo 'valor recebido: '. date_format($v_datafinal,"Y-d-m H:i:s");
```

Desta forma, no `date_format` você pode colocar o formato que desejar...

Answer (score 1):

O datepicker não modifica a ordem. Isso está vindo do seu `request`. É só tratar com PHP:

```
list($ano,$dia,$mes) = explode("-",v_datainicio);
$nova_data = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$dia;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $( ".selector" ).datepicker({
 changeYear: true
});

/ Getter
 var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

De uma olhada aqui ve se ajuda! http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/